# v4l2 Cannot recognize MPEG-4 as an input_format for ffmpeg processing

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, video-encoding

I'm on an old version of ubuntu (12.0.4) that cannot be updated / not possible to connect to internet. It comes with a bluecherry encoding compression card
https://www.bluecherrydvr.com/product/bluecherry-bc-h04120a-4-port-video-4-port-audio-h-264-pcie-hardware-compression-capture-card/
that should expose mjpeg and h264 encoding stream.

using

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video1
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xcaf3b40] Compressed: Unsupported: MPEG-4 AVC : 352x240 704x480
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xcaf3b40] Compressed: mjpeg: MJPEG:
```

I can easily record the mjpeg using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 -c:v copy out.mjpeg
```

However I need MPEG-4 AVC (from my understanding it is h264) and

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format ***anything*** -i /dev/video1 -c:v copy out.mp4
```

is not working whathever I put as input format (h264, mpeg4, ...):

```
Cannot find a proper format for codec '****' (id 27), pixel format 'none' (id -1)
```

My understanding is that v4l2 does not know what is this type and thus ffmpeg cannot do anything with it. Am I right?
What choices do I have? Is there a way to fix this? Would updating the ubuntu version will help v4l2 to recognize this input?